# MySql Inner join of 2 table with WHERE Clauses

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am making a query  to 3 Mysql tables:

```
 Sql = "SELECT " +
       "  u.iUserID, " +
       "  u.szPlayerName, " +
       "  u.szPlayerSurname, " +
       "  u.iPreferredPos, " +
       "  u.iAltPos, " +
       "  u.charType, " +
       "  c.szClubPrefix, "+
       "  tblteam.szTeamName " +

       "FROM " +
       "  tblteam" +
       "  INNER JOIN tblusers u ON (tblteam.iTeamID = u.iTeamID) " +
       "  INNER JOIN tblclubs c ON (u.iClubID = c.iClubID) " +
       "WHERE " +
           "c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 =' 2 '  AND " +
           "u.bActive = 1 " +
           "AND u.charType= 'c'" +
       "ORDER BY " +
       "  tblteam.szTeamName DESC, " +
       "  u.szPlayerSurname;";
```

my problem is that; this query only returns the data where it match `c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM'` and not where it match `u.iClubID2 =' 2 '`  please anyone can Help me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is `u.iCludID2` supposed to have the leading and trailing whitespace?

Comment: no doesn't suppose to, but I only made a mistake while posting here, in my code it is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parenthesis with respect to your preferences

```
"(c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 =' 2 ')  AND " +
           "u.bActive = 1 " +
           "AND u.charType= 'c'"
```

Comment: this looked right but, when i do something like this, I am getting Empty Table which is wrong.

Comment: what about your previous result. can you explain the constraints in the where clause

Comment: my previous result was like this; my query was returning only the data where c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' but not where u.iClubID2 ='2'

Answer (score 1):

wrap in parenthesis
(c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 ='2')

and remove the whitespace before and after 2.
Note that dealing with numbers in MySQL you don't need the '

e.g. 
iClubID2 = 2

instead of

iClubID2 ='2'

Comment: c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 ='2'

Answer (score 1):

your where clause looks like this:

WHERE c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 =' 2 '  AND u.bActive = 1 AND u.charType= 'c'

and it equivalence:

WHERE c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR ( u.iClubID2 =' 2 '  AND u.bActive = 1 AND u.charType= 'c' )

so, u.iClubID2 =' 2 ' is one of those 3 conditions must be all true.

Comment: Yes What you said, you right but now how can I solve this problem? please

Comment: @Clement Use parentheses as vick and Exbury wrote.

Comment: @Kenny I tried that way and I am get the Empty dataTable which, i know it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: Can you give us an example iClubID2 of what's in your database? I just take a wild guess that ' 2 ' doesn't make sense, because there 's a blank space before and after that char '2'.

Comment: it is actually integer 2, but I did make a collection:SELECT   
u.iUserID,  
u.szPlayerName,  
u.szPlayerSurname,
u.iPreferredPos,
u.iAltPos,
u.charType,
tblteam.szTeamName 
FROM   tblteam  
INNER JOIN tblusers u ON (tblteam.iTeamID = u.iTeamID)  
INNER JOIN tblclubs c ON (u.iClubID = c.iClubID) 
WHERE (c.szClubPrefix = 'CLM' OR u.iClubID2 =2)AND u.bActive = 1 AND u.charType= 'c' 
ORDER BY  tblteam.szTeamName DESC,   u.szPlayerSurname; and this is how my query looks like, but still am getting the wrong result. Thanks.